# How to calculate exact value of a trig function?

Tags: java, math, precision, trigonometry, pi

I am writing a "triangle solver" app for Android, and I was wondering if it would be possible to implement exact values for trig ratios and radian measures. For example, 90 degrees would be output as "pi / 2" instead of 1.57079632679...

I know that in order to get the exact value for a radian measure, I would divide it by pi and convert it to a fraction. I don't know how I would convert the decimal to a fraction.

like this:

```
int decimal = angleMeasure / Math.PI;
someMethodToTurnItIntoAFraction(decimal);
```

I don't even know where to begin with the trig ratios.

Comment: why not output 180 degrees as "180 degrees"

Comment: This is only going to be of any use for specific values; what would you want it to display for e.g. 179 degrees?

Comment: I am trying to calculate exact values for radian measures, not degrees. Though I suppose just include some statements that will detect whether an exact fractional value exists for such a value...

Comment: 180 degress is PI radians, not PI/2

Comment: @user: If you want to work in "exact" radian values, then starting with degrees is not a good idea!

Comment: X degrees is simply X/180*PI radians.  E.g. 45 degrees is 45/180*PI is 1/4*PI is PI/4.  (just simplify the fraction).

Comment: It would be better to chnage the title into something like "how to convert decimal into fraction". Good approximations can be found using continuous fractions and the algorithm described here: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51886.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the number and divide it by each of the "special" numbers: pi,e, sqrt(2), sqrt(3), sqrt(5). After each division, determine if the resulting number is close to an exact fraction. To do the last part, use the continued fraction algorithm to find good approximations to the number. There are criteria you can use in the continued fraction expansion to determine if the approximation is nearly exact. If you get a nice fraction with small numbers that is nearly exact then that's your answer - the fraction times the special number that was divided by at the beginning. Oh and consider "1" as a divisor so simple fractions come out too.

Been there, done that, works well. I don't recall the algorithm for getting approximate fractions without storing and collapsing the entire continued fraction, but it's been linked here on SO recently.

Comment: Beat me to it, but good for you +1. [Integer Relation Finding](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm)

Comment: @drvitek - What other special numbers are there? remember, the fractional part will be found automatically.

Comment: @phkaler, Well, the square root of basically every non-perfect square

Comment: Those actually don't come up too often. If you really care about those, they can be identified by squaring the number and seeing if you get really close to an integer - then remove square factors.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody stops you from using fractions as they come. Integer, Double, etc. are just objects, that can be used with 4 operations: +, -, *, /. You can use some kind of **object Fraction**, which will also perform these operations (not like operators, but like plain methods - consider BigInteger for example of such use), but do it in its own manner. For some aspects of creating new number types see [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-18.html#%_sec_2.5), and for implementation in Java see [these](http://www.merriampark.com/fractions.htm) notes.

EDIT

What I mean is not creating your `someMethodToTurnItIntoAFraction`, but using natural fractions themselves. I.e. your code will look like this:

```
Fraction f = new Fraction(angleMeasure, Fraction.PI); 
System.out.println(f.getNum() + "/" + f.getDen());
```

It will take more time, but will keep your numbers precise.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, chips compute trigonometrical functions using Taylor's polynom, which is a row of additions of fractions. So you could implement that computation and keep it in fractions. Will be slow, of course.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Comment: Fraction manipulation is much easier, then computing Taylor series.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is using Pi as a concept instead of a number. I'd do something like this:

```
class Fraction {
    public int num;
    public int den;
    public Fraction(int n,int d) {
        num=n;
       den=d;
    }
    public Fraction() {
        num=1;
        den=1;
    public double decValue() {
        return ((double)num)/((double)den);
    }
}
```

yadda, yadda....

```
 public static Fraction someMethod(double decVal) {
    Fraction f=new Fraction(1,1);
    double howclose=0.0000001; //tiny amount of error allowed
    while(abs((f.decValue()*Math.PI)-decVal)>howclose) {
        if(f.decValue()*Math.PI>decVal) {
            f.den++;
        }
        else {
            f.num++;
        }
    }
    return f;
}
```

Basically, work on getting the fraction closer and closer to the expected answer (decVal). The fraction will be in the form of:

```
num*PI
------
den
```

Basically, multiply the fraction that's in the result by Pi, and it should be *very* close to decVal.

Comment: Take a look at [Markdown help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for information on how to make your text pretty, including formatting of source code.